# Extract distinct Fields values from mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm quite new to mongodb and I'm stuck with a simple (or not) problem:

I have a collection of tagged Products like this:

```
{ "_id": "1", "tags": { "shape" : [ "shape1","shape2" ], "color": [ "col1","col2" ] },
{ "_id": "2", "tags": { "shape" : [ "shape3","shape4" ], "color": [ "col3","col4" ] },
{ "_id": "3", "tags": { "otherCategory" : [ "value1" ], "color": [ "col5","col6" ] }
```

I want to select all distinct category from this collection and have this results:

```
[ "shape", "OtherCategory" ]
```

**How can I achieve this ?** for now it seems that my only option is to find all tags and parse it manualy in the java client...seems bad ;-)

I query mongodb from a java spring client.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that there is one more way to do it is to use Map/Reduce, because `Aggregation` in MongoDB works across documents, not across collections.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I ended up with **refactoring my model**: it looks like it's not easy to make queries on documents contents without doing some Map/reduce like Konstantin said.

To solve this problem I created a new collection of Categories so that I can easily select them. This collection is populated when the Products are insert.

Comment: Refactoring your schema to meet your access needs is usually a good idea :)